# Sorting parent tags by using child tag values in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

I am trying to sort the parent nodes based on the child tag value using XSLT 1.0.
Below is my XML content:

```html
   <PPPrivPropertyLine>
    <InsuredProperties>
     <Entry>
       <ContractParts>
          <Entry>
            <ContractType>GlasInsurance</ContractType>
            <name>Suresh</name>
            </Entry>
        </ContractParts>
      </Entry>
         <Entry>
             <Buildings>
                 <Entry>
                    <AlarmClass>None_De</AlarmClass>
                    <BasementArea>10</BasementArea>
                    <InterestType>OwnerOccupied_De</InterestType>
                 </Entry>
              </Buildings>
            <ContractParts>                     
             <Entry>
                   <ContractType>Residential</ContractType>
                  </Entry>
                  <Entry>
                    <ContractType>Household</ContractType>
                  </Entry>
              </ContractParts>
          </Entry>              
        </InsuredProperties>
      </PPPrivPropertyLine>
```

There are 2 "Entry" tags in "InsuredProperties" and I want to sort the order of those 2 "Entry" tags based on 'ContractType' text like below.

Expected Output:

```html
<PPPrivPropertyLine>
    <InsuredProperties>      
     <Entry>
         <Buildings>
                 <Entry>
                    <AlarmClass>None_De</AlarmClass>
                    <BasementArea>10</BasementArea>
                    <InterestType>OwnerOccupied_De</InterestType>
                 </Entry>
              </Buildings>
          <ContractParts>
          <Entry>
            <ContractType>Residential</ContractType>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
            <ContractType>Household</ContractType>
            </Entry>
        </ContractParts>
     </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ContractParts>
          <Entry>
            <ContractType>GlasInsurance</ContractType>
            <name>Suresh</name>
            </Entry>
            </ContractParts>
        </Entry>            
    </InsuredProperties>
   </PPPrivPropertyLine>
```

I have tried with below approach. But the result is not correct. Please help me out. Thank you!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  >

    <!-- copy all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
       
    <xsl:template match="PPPrivPropertyLine/InsuredProperties">      
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Entry">
        <xsl:sort select="ContractType" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me out, thank you!

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: @54ka Added XSLT script that I've tried

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Please explain the exact rule you want to apply to the sort.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : i want to sort out in ascending/descending order based on contract Type. for ex: When we apply ascending order - Expected output is [GlassInsurance, HouseholdInsurance, ResdinetialBuildingInsurance] . Below solution helped me out to some extent. i mean out of 600 xmls 500 are passed. remaining 100 failed due to unknown reason. ResdentialBuildingInsurance is not sorting properly. See this ex: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/6

Comment: You are repeating instead of explaining. I don't know how to sort entries based on contract type when some entries have more than one type.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Thanks for the response. We can do sort like this "<xsl:sort select="ContractParts/Entry/ContarctType/text()" data-type="text" order="descending"/>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing your code

```
<xsl:sort select="ContractType" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="descending"/>
```

Comment: Yes Tried. but no luck. i just edited my question. the sorting order should be done with 'ContractType' text. Inside the ContractPart tag I have multiple items (more than 10 tags) in realtime project.
http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsW/50

Comment: @SwathiVenigalla : it is perfect as per your expected output https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH

Comment: hey it's worked. Thank you so much!. The only difference with my code and yours  is "<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>". I have not used this line. Thank god. You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: when i placed this script in my project, it si not sorting because we have <Buildings> tag is there. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/1

Comment: updated; https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/2

Comment: I have adjusted little bit in your code as per my requirement. It's working now. Thank you so much

Comment: Any idea why it is not sorting inside the <ContractParts> [Expected: GlassInsurance, HouseholdInsurance and residentialBuilding Insurance] when we apply ascending order https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/3

Comment: have you tried anything? consider to ask a new question with your attempt to adapt the suggestions made here to the more complex input and a proper explanation.

Comment: i got afraid to put actual data. Anyways I've sorted out this problem. it's working fine now. "<xsl:sort select="ContarctType/text()" data-type="text" order="descending"/>". I don't know how "dot (.)" works but got solution based on ContractType tag. I could not able to explain the actual requirement as this is my first post on this community. And many thanks for your help and support. Thank you!